# drop-shadow filter on dropdown menu is not working in Safari browser

Tags: html, css, blazor, bootstrap-5

[image: picture when the Nav item is hovered]
--> picture when the Nav item (products) is hovered, displays a dropdown menu

[image: picture of nav item after hovering is removed]
--> picture of nav item (products) after hovering is removed (shadow is not removed even after the dropdown menu is gone)

There is a -webkit-filter style attribute written for dropdown menu (using bootstrap 5). Here is the dropdown menu style:

[image] --> closed stated

[image] --> display is set to block state

**Approaches tried:**

1. added -webkit-filters and -webkit-appearance to none when the dropdown display is hidden and reassigned only when display is set to block. Similarly, tried with filters and background attributes.
   [image]

This problem occurs only in Safari browser and not in any others. Please help me out since this is my first time running into cross-browser problem

Comment: problem replication is in here:  https://codepen.io/cswskeerthi/pen/MWmBReR

Answer (score 0):

adding this to the dropdown-menu style has fixed the problem.

-webkit-box-shadow: 3px -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);